# PHP conditional inside loop wont work

Tags: php

I want to check name in array and if it matched display a message. the problem is the conditional will go to the else statement.

```
<?php
$names = ['user1','user2','test1','test2'];
$name = "user1";
for($i=0; $i < count($names) ; $i++) {
    if($name == $names[$i]) {
       echo "you are registered";
    }else {
      echo "you are unregistered";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: If you look closely it goes to the IF first and then the else

Comment: You loop through all the elements so you will end up with 3 `'unregistered'` and once a `'registered'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you dont loop through all the array once you find a registered user try this contruct instead

```
$names = ['user1','user2','test1','test2'];
$name = "user1";
for($i=0; $i < count($names) ; $i++) {
    if($name == $names[$i]) {
        echo "you are registered";
        // found a user, terminate the for loop
        break;
    }
    // if you dont find a registeted user you will do this
    echo "you are unregistered";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use PHP's built-in [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) instead of reinventing the wheel:

```
if (in_array($name, $names)) {
    echo "you are registered";
} else {
    echo "you are unregistered";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you don't want to print out 3 "you are unregistered", so the loop's function should be just to figure out if the user is registered. You can set a boolean to true if you find the name:

```
<?php
$names = ['user1','user2','test1','test2'];
$name = "user1";
$registered = false;
for($i=0; $i < count($names) ; $i++) {
    if($name == $names[$i]) {
       registered = true;
    }
}
if(registered){
    echo "you are registered";
} else {
    echo "you are not registered";
}
?>
```

Alternatively, you can use `in_array()` which is less verbose and easier to understand:

```
$names = ['user1','user2','test1','test2'];
$name = "user1";
if(in_array($name, $names)){
    echo "you are registered";
} else {
    echo "you are not registered";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As note: Security relevat? Use === to compare values

```
f($name == $names[$i]) { ...

f($name === $names[$i]) {
```

And break the loop on the first match, Always, like already mentioned